# how to skip through a loop when debugging R code

Tags: debugging, r

I am new debugging in R using `traceback()` and `option(error=recover)` and `debug(function)` to try to find the reason of an error I have in an R package.

I am debugging a function with a big loop and I want to 'step out' of the loop into the next block. How can I do that? I know that you can put breakpoints, but I don't know where the loop is nor which is the next step. I am in an only text environment so the graphical help of the debug package probably does not help.

To sum up, how to step out of a loop when debugging, and how to step into a function for debug when you are already debugging?

Probably this has been already answered and I have missed it. I have seen several SO R debug question but none answering this part that I am aware.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'm fairly sure R's help system works even if you're not using a GUI. Try typing `?debug` and see what happens. You ought to be informed that typing `c` or `cont` will

> continue to the end of the current context: e.g. to the end of the loop if within a loop or to the end of the function.

Comment: `browser()` can also be helpful to let you see what the values of your variables are at any point within the loop, see `?browser`.

Comment: I have just  realize that `c` goes to the end of the current context when I pressed `c` to go to the end of the script and only went to the end of the loop. I had from a a course hand-outs "c or cont (Continue execution without single stepping. )" and this was misleading me. Thanks